# How to break the js files into chunks in vue cli 3 with webpack performance object?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I have done a project using vue cli v3. After building the project I saw 2 warnings i.e.

```
warning

asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).

This can impact web performance.

Assets:

  js/chunk-vendors.2557157d.js (474 KiB)

warning

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.

Entrypoints:

  app (617 KiB)

      js/chunk-vendors.2557157d.js

      css/app.821fcb13.css

      js/app.b5a47a94.js
```

Now upon inspection I saw that if I add the following in webpack config

```
performance: {
maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
maxAssetSize: 512000
}
```

then it will automatically break the js files into small chunks. Now in vue cli 3 there is no webpack.config file.

So, if you can please guide how to implement this so that files get auto chunked when it crosses some limit, it will be really helpful.

This is where I saw it: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3486#issuecomment-397915908

Looking forward to your reply.

P.S.: I've read [this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/03/26/vue-cli-3/) and tried creating the **vue.config.js** file and added the following inside the file

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
    }
  }
}
```

But it didn't do anything. Can anyone please help to let me know what should I do to make sure my js file chunks do not cross the recommended size by vue?

### Update

As per the answer by Linus Borg I tried putting both of the following codes in the `vue.config.js` file. **Try 1**:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    splitChunks: {
            minSize: 10000,
            maxSize: 250000,
        }
  }
}
```

and **Try 2**:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                node_vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    chunks: "all",
                    priority: 1
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

After both of then when I built my project for production. I saw the same warning, without changing any size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf04W.jpg
It seems none of them are affecting any changes. Any help?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following added to my **vue.config.js** file is what finally chunked all my vendor assets when executing `npm run build` for my @vue/cli project (version 3.0.4).

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack:{
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        minSize: 10000,
        maxSize: 250000,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hide warnings

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack:{
    performance: {
      hints: false
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        minSize: 10000,
        maxSize: 250000,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @iSaumya If you'd like to hide the warning you can use the edited configuration above.  However, unless you start removing dependencies or do further code splitting you can only reduce certain file chunks so far.  You might also try reducing the `maxSize` value to something below 250000.

Comment: Hi, in my vue project I've done extensive code splitting. I've imported each component, router asycly. Unfortunately can't load the import a from 'b' asyncly as that is used inside the code, But in mode places I've done code splitting. Just can't split the vendors.

Answer (score 17):

You misunderstand the settings that you changed, probably because you misread the issu comment that you linked to.

Those are *not* limits that tell webpack how/when to split a chunk, they only define limts above which the warning is displayed in the console, that's all.

What you really want is to change the settings for [`splitChunks`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/). Unfortunately that option an be pretty complicated to set up for a beginner, so I would recommend [this article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/webpack-4-splitchunks-plugin-d9fbbe091fd0) to get a better understanding of how it actually works.

However what this article doesn't cover is that in recent versions, a new [exerimental option](https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/1014596702899236866) was added to `splitChunks`: `maxSize`.

It should work something like this:

```
configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            minSize: 10000,
            maxSize: 250000,
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind it's experimental, so the more reliable way would be to config splitchunks to create chunks that don't exceed your size limit by manually putting different dependencies into different chunks with `splitChunks.cacheGroups`.

Comment: Hi, I tried putting both of the following codes in the `vue.config.js` file. Try 1: https://pastebin.com/9k3EsuUf and Try 2: https://pastebin.com/CjqfURfd 
After both of then when I built my project for production. I saw the same warning, without changing any size: https://i.imgur.com/7Hp7SXC.jpg
It seems none of them are affecting any changes. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

this is my config file, and it works in my project, please try it.

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        performance: {
            hints: "warning", // enum
            maxAssetSize: 1048576, // int (in bytes),
            maxEntrypointSize: 1048576, // int (in bytes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did use the above-mentioned configurations and I still see the following warnings: https://pastebin.com/sxY38XFC
What to do?